# Error : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.persistence.Entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-orm

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/persistence/Entity
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.<clinit>(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:108)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.persistence.Entity
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

Please tell me ways to solve this exception.

Comment: Hi there! To help us better understand the issue, could you please add more details? For a starter, [edit] the post, include the relevant code and highlight the problematic code.  Thanks!

Comment: Please add the `pom.xml` if you have one.

Comment: this is no question, this is a command. I suggest reading the guidelines carefully, as you will not come far on SO otherwise.